# EF Core, does it support Has One Through?

Tags: entity-framework

Does EF core support Has One Through, similar to [Laravel Eloquent Relationship - Through](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#:%7E:text=%7D-,Has%20One%20Through,proceeding%20through%20a%20third%20model.) ?

If so how would I configure this ?